# file not created by file handling in php

Tags: php, file-handling

I am write following code for create demo.txt file but it not working.

```
<?php
$my_file = 'demo.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$my_file);
?>
```

> Cannot open file:demo.txt.

But demo.txt file already created in same directory. What thing missing here?

Comment: Try using an absolute file path like `/home/user_name/public_html/demo.txt` or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Check if the file under have "777" permission on every directory of the file path.
>   It will need it to access the file. Also check you used the correct path to open

Comment: This is ok for a test, but in terms of security it is probably a bad idea to use '777' permissions. I would recommend that you try to find a safer solution than relaxing file system permissions.